# Xamarin FontImageSource Glyph not showing up

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, xamarin.android, glyph

I am trying to add a font icon using the following code:

```
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{OnPlatform iOS=Ionicons,
                                        Android=ionicons.ttf#}"
                Glyph="&#xf37f;"
                Size="44"
                Color="Red" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

which I found on the [official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts). However, the icon doesn't show up on my Android phone, instead I get this (symbol not found placeholder):
[image: Unknown symbol placeholder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You miss a "#" after `Android=ionicons.ttf` :

   ```
   <Image>
       <Image.Source>
           <FontImageSource
               FontFamily="{OnPlatform iOS=Ionicons,Android=ionicons.ttf#}"
               Glyph="&#xf37f;"
               Size="44"
               Color="Red" />
       </Image.Source>
   </Image>
   ```
2. I don't think there is a icon font named `f37f` in the [ionicons](https://ionicons.com/v2/)

Comment: 1. It doesn't work even with the #; 2. `f37f` is a valid ionicon according to this official cheatsheet: https://ionicons.com/v2/cheatsheet.html (Howcome you assumed it wasn't or am I seeing something wrong?)

Comment: Where does your ionicons.ttf file comes from? Are you sure it is the same as the v2.0.0 you referred in the link? I test other icons and it all work well with #,=.

Comment: Good question sir, for some reason I thought it was already present on the android system, so I didn't put it in my Assets folder. Now I did and it works, thanks!